# 'DepartmentDataDelegate' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

Tags: ios, swift, api, delegates, protocols

I am using Protocol and Delegates for saving api data into delegate method and in another class, fetching it. But in second class, when i declared this property. It shows an error message.

> 'DepartmentDataDelegate' cannot be constructed because it has no
>   accessible initializers

**Class A :**
Add protocol for saving api data into the delegate method.

```
protocol DepartmentDataDelegate {
    func showDepttData(departments: [String : Any])
}

var delegate: DepartmentDataDelegate?
```

Stored api data into protocol method

```
do {
                //create json object from data
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: [Any]] {
                    //print("POST Method :\(json)")


                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        for eachDepartment in json["departments"]!
                        {
                            let eachData = eachDepartment as! [String: Any]

                            self.delegate?.showDepttData(departments: eachData)
                        }
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }

                    // handle json...
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

**Class B :** 
This class is fetching the department data and print here.

```
class ShowEmpVC: UIViewController, DepartmentDataDelegate {

    //Department Data Delegate
    var depttDelegate = DepartmentDataDelegate()

    var depttData = [String : Any]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        depttDelegate = self
        print("Departmens  are  :   \(depttData)")
    }
}
```

Comment: you actually cannot Construct it , you need to create Reference to class A in which protocol is declared In class b just using that Class A Reference set the delegate to self

Comment: i am using first time, can u please explain how to use that ?

Comment: In your `Class B`, you would do something like `var obj = ClassA()` and then `obj.delegate = self`

Comment: Is this query solved ?

Answer (score 0):

In your protocol not have a `init()` func. So you not call `DepartmentDataDelegate()`. Try this:

Class A:

```
protocol DepartmentDataDelegate {
    func showDepttData(departments: [String : Any])
}

static var delegate: DepartmentDataDelegate?
```

Class B:

```
class ShowEmpVC: UIViewController, DepartmentDataDelegate {

    var depttData = [String : Any]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        depttDelegate = self
        print("Departmens  are  :   \(depttData)")
    }

   override func showDepttData(departments: [String : Any]){
      // code
  }
}
```

I not sure if needs `override` key.

Answer (score 0):

**Protocol class**

```
import UIKit

protocol sampleProtocol : class {
    func getValues(valuess:String)
}

class sampleClass {
    /// Shared Instance - So without creating a new Instance i  can make use of its function
    static let shared = sampleClass()
    /// Delegate Object
    var delegate : sampleProtocol?

    /// Sample Func which will send data using protocol
    func sendData(){
        /// Called whnen data is to be Transmitted
        delegate?.getValues(valuess: "output")
    }
}
```

**Usage -- Destination Class -- Your case ShowEmpVC**

```
import UIKit

class sampleVC: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        /// Make use of Shared Instance Created so, You need not to Re-allocate a New instance just to make use of Delegate
        sampleClass.shared.delegate = self
    }
}

/// Assign class to Protocol
extension sampleVC : sampleProtocol
{
    /// Protocol stub
    func getValues(valuess: String) {
        /// Get Value
        print(valuess)
    }
}
```